# Regressing over tiny floats with Neural Networks

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, methodology

I am trying to regress over very small `float`s - of the magnitude `[1e-2, 9e-3]`. They're mostly in this range.

Using simple `MSE` (Mean Squared Error) loss and backpropagating against it does not lead to very good results. The networks get the answer usually in the right neighbourhood, but fails to achieve even *decent* precision. This implies `MSE` is penalizing less for small differences

I tried checking some articles and results published by people, but they don't seem to yield any significant results.

What are the common *techniques* used to train networks on such precise data? what **loss** and **activation** functions are usually utilized for such data?

Comment: Did you standardize the data? Are you bound to using NN?

Comment: Yep, only NNs. and no, the data is not standardized (do you mean as a standard Gaussian distribution?)

Comment: You could multiply $y$ by say 100000 in order to avoid small floats. I would expect that standard loss functions also work better in this case. Maybe Huber loss would also help since it combines MSE, MAE properties to some extent https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47840527/using-tensorflow-huber-loss-in-keras